# The values in the ACF Repeater fields is null when the values for the same repeater field is updated in other languages?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wpml

I have a site in three languages and when I edit the repeater field for one of the languages, the value of the repeater field in other languages becomes null. This is only for some of the repeater fields in the site.

Comment: Is it a multisite-network? Wich version of WordPress and ACF?

Comment: No, it's not a multisite-network. WordPress version => 5.3.2
ACF Pro => 5.8.7

Comment: Maybe it affect only the fields you created before installing wpml?

Comment: This fields were created before installing WPML.

Comment: Have you activated `Advanced Translation Editor.`

Comment: @HowardE Nope, I have not activated `Advanced Translation Editor` and instead using `WPML's Classic Translation Editor.`

Comment: @prajwal_stha it seems like you probably need to ensure you have all of the extensions for WPML that they recommend for ACF... no?

Comment: @HowardE I believe I have all of the extensions for WPML that is recommended for ACF.
`Advanced Custom Fields Multilingual => 1.6.0
Advanced Custom Fields PRO => 5.8.7
WPML Media => 2.5.5
WPML Multilingual CMS => 4.3.6
WPML String Translation => 3.0.6
WPML Translation Management => 2.9.4`

Comment: Did you create a translation of your ACF fields? It's not obvious, but if I recall correctly you need to have fields for every language.

Comment: By default every field in acf is not translateble in wpml, you need to enable it manualy for every single field

Answer (score 0):

Go to WPML/Settings/Custom Fields Translation and select radio button "Copy once" for every field.
In that case, when you change on another language that ACF Field will not be replaced on another language